# In what cases should I personally sanitize input & output when using the Database Abstraction Layer

Tags: 7, database, security

I'm trying to get a clearer sense of where security vulnerabilities on my site may lie. At no point in my code do I ever query the MySQL database directly; I always use the Database Abstraction Layer (db_query(), etc). Under what circumstances may this not provide sufficient protection against SQL injection attacks?

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `db_query()` all the time without directly inserting variables, but using the arguments.

For example this is right: `db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid = :nid", array(':nid' => $nid));` it's perfect, you don't have to care about something else (except critical bug directly in Drupal).

On the other hand, if you do it directly: `db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE nid = $nid");` you expose your site to SQL Injection.

From my own experience, Drupal alone (without other modules) is very secure and many times we tried to hack it with professionals.

Comment: The other big thing to consider is if you are adding a table (or column, or...) directly to the query. Use something like db_escape_table - http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/db_escape_table/6